# Storing a list of unknown object types in an RDBMS?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

### Background

Im working on a game and i want to persist the gameworld. This gameworld is made out of entities looking like this.

```java
    public class Entity{
      public Set<Object> obj;
    }
```

There many, many different object types i need to store, about 100. Thats why the list of objects is required. Some of those objects reference other "Entity" objects aswell. Causing circular references.

### Question

Is there a way to define such a loose 1:n relation in sql ?

Comment: Serialize your object before saving into the database, and de-serialize during retrieving. Serialization method may be any which produces the value compatible with your DBMS. For example, it can be JSON, XML, etc... Some properties may be stored in separate columns in non-packed form additionally for performance improving (for example, object type as ENUM and object identifier as BIGINT or UUID).

Comment: Adding alternatie to akina's answer if data is unknown use nosql